# What is momentum in a quantum sense?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, momentum

I’m currently taking my first course in quantum mechanics, and was looking over my notes on wavefunctions of particles with definite momentum.

Suppose $\psi=Ce^{ikx}$, we know from DeBroglie that this particle has a definite momentum because it has a definite wavelength.

We can calculate the expectation value of $p$ by evaluating $$⟨p⟩_{\psi}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}x\ \psi^*(x)\hat{p} \ \psi (x).$$

That being said, is this momentum the same as in classical mechanics, or is this a different physical quantity?

Comment: What does it mean for a quantum mechanical quantity to be "the same" as a classical one?

Comment: Dimensionally analogous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "classical limit" $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, quantum mechanics reproduces the predictions of classical physics.

The exact definition of momentum is the one you gave. In the classical limit, this quantity behaves exactly the same way as the classical momentum behaves in classical mechanics. Outside of the classical limit, it behaves differently (and in a way that agrees with experiment).

One way to make this more explicit is using [Ehrenfest's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem). A special case of that theorem tells us how the expectation value of the momentum behaves in quantum mechanics (this is an exact, quantum mechanical expression)
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{d}{dt} \langle x \rangle &=& \frac{\langle p \rangle}{m} \\
\frac{d}{dt}\langle p \rangle &=& \langle V'(x) \rangle \\
\end{eqnarray}
which look very similar to Hamilton's equations in classical mechanics.
However, this set of equations is **not** saying that the expectation values of momentum and position obey Hamilton's equations, since in the second equation, $\langle V'(x) \rangle \neq V'(\langle x \rangle)$.

Nevertheless, in the limit when the position is sharply peaked around a particular point, $\langle V'(x)\rangle \approx V'(\langle x \rangle)$. In the limit $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, a wavefunction peaked around a point in position space will not spread out, and so the wavefunction will remain peaked at a given position as time evolves assuming it was sharply peaked to begin with. In this limit, the expectation values for the position and momentum operators in quantum mechanics, obey the usual classical equations of motion.

Comment: This is a brilliant explanation, and it’s not difficult to understand but somehow tells a lot; thank you so much!

Comment: @empty-engineer To be fair, this isn't my explanation; you can also find it in Griffifths' quantum mechanics book and on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem#Relation_to_Classical_Physics).